# Attribute for a class object

Tags: python, python-3.8

sorry for my poor English.
I' am new in python.
I have the code below that seem not working. I cannot figure out why :

```
import datetime

# class Franchise: def init(self, address, menus): self.address = address self.menus = menus
class Franchise:
  def __init__(self, address, menus):
    self.address = address
    self.menus = menus

  def __repr__(self):
    return "Our address is {address}".format(address = self.address)

  def available_menus(self, time):
    list_menus = []
    for menu in self.menus:
      if menu.start_time <= time <= menu.end_time:
        list_menus.append(menu)
    return list_menus

# `class Menu: def init(self, name, items, start_time, end_time): self.name = name self.items= items self.start_time = start_time self.end_time = end_time`
class Menu:
  def __init__(self, name, items, start_time, end_time):
    self.name = name
    self.items = items
    self.start_time = start_time
    self.end_time = end_time

  def __repr__(self):
    return "{name} menu available from {start} to {end}".format(name = self.name, start = self.start_time, end = self.end_time)

  def calculate_bill(self, purchased_items):
    bill = 0
    for item in purchased_items:
      if item in self.items:
        bill += self.items.get(item)
    return bill


brunch = Menu("brunch", {
  'pancakes': 7.50, 'waffles': 9.00, 'burger': 11.00, 'home fries': 4.50, 'coffee': 1.50, 'espresso': 3.00, 'tea': 1.00, 'mimosa': 10.50, 'orange juice': 3.50
}, datetime.datetime.strptime('11', '%H').strftime('%I %p'), datetime.datetime.strptime('16', '%H').strftime('%I %p'))

early_bird = Menu("early_bird", {
  'salumeria plate': 8.00, 'salad and breadsticks (serves 2, no refills)': 14.00, 'pizza with quattro formaggi': 9.00, 'duck ragu': 17.50, 'mushroom ravioli (vegan)': 13.50, 'coffee': 1.50, 'espresso': 3.00, 
}, datetime.datetime.strptime('15', '%H').strftime('%I %p'), datetime.datetime.strptime('18', '%H').strftime('%I %p'))

dinner = Menu("dinner", {
  'crostini with eggplant caponata': 13.00, 'ceaser salad': 16.00, 'pizza with quattro formaggi': 11.00, 'duck ragu': 19.50, 'mushroom ravioli (vegan)': 13.50, 'coffee': 2.00, 'espresso': 3.00, 
}, datetime.datetime.strptime('17', '%H').strftime('%I %p'), datetime.datetime.strptime('23', '%H').strftime('%I %p'))

kids = Menu("kids", {
  'chicken nuggets': 6.50, 'fusilli with wild mushrooms': 12.00, 'apple juice': 3.00
}, datetime.datetime.strptime('11', '%H').strftime('%I %p'), datetime.datetime.strptime('21', '%H').strftime('%I %p'))


flagship_store = Franchise("1232 West End Road", ['brunch', 'early_bird', 'dinner', 'dinner', 'kids'])

new_installment = Franchise("12 East Mulberry Street", ['brunch', 'early_bird', 'dinner', 'dinner', 'kids'])


print(new_installment.available_menus(12))
```

I Keep getting the error below:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'start_time'

Can Someone help me here.
What Am I missing here ?

Comment: The menus you give to the Franchise constructor should be Menu objects. Remove the quotes around the names of the menus. e.g. 'brunch' -> brunch

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Franchise` constructor receives list of `Menu` objects, not strings.

Change:

```
flagship_store = Franchise("1232 West End Road", ['brunch', 'early_bird', 'dinner', 'dinner', 'kids'])

new_installment = Franchise("12 East Mulberry Street", ['brunch', 'early_bird', 'dinner', 'dinner', 'kids'])
```

To:

```
flagship_store = Franchise("1232 West End Road", [brunch, early_bird, dinner, dinner, kids])

new_installment = Franchise("12 East Mulberry Street", [brunch, early_bird, dinner, dinner, kids])
```